# Add vertical space between full width card in material-design-lite

Tags: css, material-design-lite

How to add space between MDL card component?

```
<div class="demo-card-event mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
    <h4>
      Featured event:<br>
      May 24, 2016<br>
      7-11pm
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Add to Calendar
    </a>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <i class="material-icons">event</i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="demo-card-event mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
    <h4>
      Featured event:<br>
      May 24, 2016<br>
      7-11pm
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Add to Calendar
    </a>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <i class="material-icons">event</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the card component there is no space between the cards they are completely joined end to end.

Is there any inbuilt class to add space or we need to add that manually or is there any mistake in my code.

Tried adding `mdl-layout-spacer` class still did not work.

Found a old thread that was not answered by any person.

[Vertical adjustment between cards in Material Design Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108488/vertical-adjustment-between-cards-in-material-design-lite)

Edit:

is this the correct way to add grid?

```
<div class="mdl-grid" style="max-width: 90%;">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--9-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">

    </div>

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-typography--text-center">

        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
                    <h4>
                        Featured event:<br>
                        May 24, 2016<br>
                        7-11pm
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                        Add to Calendar
                    </a>
                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <i class="material-icons">event</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make use of the grid and put each card inside a column: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid

Comment: can we use the nested grid in mdl? because I already have a grid in the parent element.

Comment: Yes, as many nested as you want.  It will add additional spacing every time unless you use `mdl-grid--no-spacing`.  Also, it will divide the inner columns the same way as the outer columns (so you could have 12 columns inside of 12 columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your a row wrapper around the cards and add a cell class to the card, or wrap each card in a cell class, depending on the effect you want.

```html
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="mdl-grid" style="max-width: 90%;">
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--9-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
</div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-typography--text-center">
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet demo-card-event mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
          <h4>
            Featured event:<br>
            May 24, 2016<br>
            7-11pm
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            Add to Calendar
          </a>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <i class="material-icons">event</i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet demo-card-event mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
          <h4>
            Featured event:<br>
            May 24, 2016<br>
            7-11pm
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            Add to Calendar
          </a>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <i class="material-icons">event</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** with nested grids.

Comment: So we need to use a grid system just like bootstrap. Thanks for the code. Can you put a code how to properly nest grids? check my question I updated how I nest grids. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your split is correct, although your cards are going to be very small before they reach tablet size.  See my updated answer

Comment: I think I have to read the docs completely to understand MDL. Thanks for spending your time to help me (Y)